# One word for "Having to accept something after numerous co-incidences even though it is against your rationale"

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes you have to accept something based on numerous events asserting it without any tangible proof. For example, let's say a person survives an accident thrice in a day. It is likely that people, in such a case, would accept the reason to be some divine intervention, even if it is against their rationale. Perhaps because of lack of proof. Is there a single word for this situation?

UPDATE: It would be preferable if that word can be used as a verb.

Comment: Innumeracy?  Misunderstanding of probability theory?

Comment: Close, but I think there must be a non-scientific word too.

Comment: Humpty-Dumpty tells us that if you make a word do that much work you're going to have to pay it extra.

Comment: @StoneyB That's hilariously disappointing.

Comment: Three words is as close as I can get: [Delusions of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delusions_of_reference). But I don't think it's quite what you want.

Comment: I think your premise is flawed. I think someone would only accept these things as divine intervention if that aligned with their "rationale", otherwise they would simply say, "It's *inexplicable*."

Comment: *Empirical Rationalization*?

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question. Right now, another phrase that is consistent with your description is 'experimental evidence' which is counter to most of the answers. Also, you could think you can rationally claim that you are Napoleon, but many people tell you differently and you don't speak French. So maybe it would be 'accepting reality'.

Comment: Why, precisely, would one *have* to accept something against their rationale?  Do you mean accepting something *despite* it being against their stated/conscious rationale?

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Answer (score 1):

The term **synchronicity** [means](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/synchronicity)

> the simultaneous occurrence of events that appear significantly related but have no discernible causal connection

This does not convey any causative agency.

**Providence** is a term that [can suggest](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/providence) divine or other supernatural causation

> a. (Christianity) God's foreseeing protection and care of his creatures
>
> b.such protection and care as manifest by some other force

Comment: Synchronicity is very close. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

***Empirical Rationalization***

This term has a positive connotation to it as against the kind of fatalistic negativity suggested in the OP's example of "even if it is against their rationale."

Or, merely,
*Statistical Rationalization*

Comment: Empirical rationalization is a bit different.